# Dumping Twitter Streaming API tweets as-is to Apache Cassandra for post-processing

Tags: database, api, twitter, streaming, cassandra

I am using the Twitter Streaming API to monitor several keywords/users. I am planning to dump the tweets json strings I get from twitter directly as-is to cassandra database and do post processing on them later.

Is such a design practical? Will it scale up when I have millions of tweets?

Things I will do later include getting top followed users, top hashtags etc. I would like to save the stream as is for mining them later for any new information that I may not know of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is important is not so much the number of tweets as the rate at which they arrive.  Cassandra can easily handle thousands of writes per second, which should be fine (Twitter currently generates around 1200 tweets per second in total, and you will probably only get a small fraction of those).

However, tweets per second are highly variable.  In the aftermath of a heavy spike in writes, you may see some slowdown in range queries.  See the Acunu blog posts on [Cassandra under heavy write load part i](http://www.acunu.com/blogs/richard-low/cassandra-under-heavy-write-load-part-i/) and [part ii](http://www.acunu.com/blogs/richard-low/cassandra-under-heavy-write-load-part-ii/) for some discussion of the problem and ways to solve it.

In addition to storing the raw json, I would extract some common features that you are almost certain to need, such as the user ID and the hashtags, and store those separately as well.  This will save you a lot of processing effort later on.

Another factor to consider is to plan for how the data stored will grow over time.  Cassandra can scale very well, but you need to have a strategy in place for how to keep the load balanced across your cluster and how to add nodes as your database grows.  Adding nodes can be a painful experience if you haven't planned out how to allocate tokens to new nodes in advance.  Waiting until you have an overloaded node before adding a new one is a good way to make your cluster fall down.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily store millions of tweets in cassandra.

For processing the tweets and getting stats such as top followed users, hashtags look at [brisk](http://www.datastax.com/products/brisk) from DataStax which builds on top of cassandra.